# Post request not bind data with POJO class in spring mvc Rest api.

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, http-post

I am very new to rest api concept. I am trying to implement a simple method that can receive a post method. The problem is request hit the method but the not bind the data with the POJO class. 
Here is the my code.

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public CompileRequest home(@ModelAttribute CompileRequest compileRequest) {
    logger.info("user name : {}", compileRequest.getUserName()); // null
    logger.info("input file path : {}", compileRequest.getInputFilePath()); //null
    return compileRequest;
}
}
```

I did not use @RequestBody because it gives me 415 http error. 
And this is my POJO class.

```
@Data // use lombok for getter and setter. 
public class CompileRequest {
   private String userName;
   private String inputFilePath;
}
```

[image: POSTMAN view]

The `userName` and `inputFilePath` field is remaining `null`. I am not understand why not the data binding is not working. How can I fix this ?

Thank you.

Comment: what is the stacktrace you get when u use @RequestBody ?

Comment: add these 3 dependency and then use @RequestBody see if it works https://gist.github.com/sazzadislam-dsi/a90a3ea0c6d8a41e13acc2024aeb02ec

Comment: @LynAs dependency already been added in pom. And it does not generate any stacktrace in my end but in the response it says `The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.`.

Comment: can you see getter/setter in structure tab??

Comment: @LynAs yes. I think lombok is working properly. I have called getter/setter method in other part of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the return as following. Since u want rest response it also gives you option to send proper status code

```
public ResponseEntity<?> home(@RequestBody CompileRequest compileRequest) {

   return return ResponseEntity.ok(compileRequest);
}
```

add the following on top of `CompileRequest` class

```
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
```

Also add the following dependency if you don't have it already

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Finally send data as Json

```
{

   "userName" : "name",
   "inputFilePath": "path"

}
```